# Get return value of function imported from another module in Node

Tags: node.js, express

I have a main app.js file and  a helper.js file as so:

helper.js:

```
  exports.lookup = function(id){

  var xml = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?> \
              <data>\
               <key>aSecretKey</key>\
               <request>read</request>\
               <id>'+id+'</id> \
              </data>';

  var options = {
    url:'https://somesite.com',
    headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/xml'},
    body:xml
  };

  request.post(options, function (e, r, body){
    var data = JSON.parse(parser.toJson(body)).result;

    return data;

  });
};
```

app.js:

```
app.post('/customer', (req, res) => {

  flg.lookup(req.body.id);  <---- How do I access what this imported function returns?

eg, console.log(result of flg.lookup)

  res.render('index', {customerEmail:'test5@test5.com'}); 

});
```

I'd like to pass the function from the helper file and return it's result in app.js.

Currently, it is returning only undefined, which is strange.

Comment: You need to use Promise. As API calls are asynchronous, your function returns before the call is completed. That's why you getting undefined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Problem / solution

`helper.js`performs an asynchronous http request. Hence, `return data` is executed after the function lookup has returned.

You want to use a *callback* function instead of `return`.

You may want to read some documentation about how to deal with asynchronous programming in node.js, here is a [reference article](https://flaviocopes.com/javascript-callbacks/).

#### Corrected code

Updated code would look like this:

helper.js

```
  exports.lookup = function(id, callback){

  var xml = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?> \
              <data>\
               <key>aSecretKey</key>\
               <request>read</request>\
               <id>'+id+'</id> \
              </data>';

  var options = {
    url:'https://somesite.com',
    headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/xml'},
    body:xml
  };

  request.post(options, function (e, r, body){
    var data = JSON.parse(parser.toJson(body)).result;

    callback(null, data);

  });
};
```

app.js

```
app.post('/customer', (req, res) => {

  flg.lookup(req.body.id, function(err, res) {
      // this callback function is called by lookup function with the result
      if (err)
          throw err

      console.log('result is', res);

      res.render('index', {customerEmail:'test5@test5.com'}); 

  });

});
```

#### Alternative solutions

You may also solve the problem ysing `Promises` or `async / await`, I let you look these up in your favorite search engine.

Comment: Perfect, thanks - makes sense. As new user can't upvote but this is correct solution and promptly answered thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Because request dosen't support promises you can wrap your api call in a [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) and use it with [async await](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function)

helper.js

```
exports.lookup = function(id){

  var xml = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?> \
              <data>\
              <key>aSecretKey</key>\
              <request>read</request>\
              <id>'+id+'</id> \
              </data>';

  var options = {
    url:'https://somesite.com',
    headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/xml'},
    body:xml
  };

  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    request.post(options, function (e, r, body){
      if (e) {
        reject(e);
      }

      var data = JSON.parse(parser.toJson(body)).result;
      resolve(data);
    });
  });
};
```

app.js

```
app.post('/customer', async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const result = await flg.lookup(req.body.id);
    console.log(result);
    res.render('index', {customerEmail:'test5@test5.com'});
  catch (e) {
    // do something with the error
  }
});
```